# mysql valid json causes Missing a comma or '}' after an object member

Tags: mysql, json

I get the following exception:

```
    SQLSTATE[22032]: <<Unknown error>>: 3140 Invalid JSON text: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 19 in value for column 'requests.calendar_attendee'. 
(SQL: UPDATE `requests` SET `calendar_attendee` = (CASE WHEN `id` = '31241690' THEN '{"firstName":"jon \"doe\""}' 
    ELSE `calendar_attendee` END), `updated_at` = (CASE WHEN `id` = '31241690' THEN '2022-11-17 20:48:36' 
    ELSE `updated_at` END) WHERE `id` IN("31241690");)
```

I am aware that using case when then does not make sense for this query. The actual query can have many more cases.

I don't understand what it is complaining about. The json is valid:

`{"firstName":"jon \"doe\""}`

Comment: Hi Chris, bee a while. Would you please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the back slash as well:

Try: `THEN '{"firstName":"jon \\"doe\\""}'`

You can check it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-values

search on that page for "escape"